# Update and set using SQL cursor SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I have a question about the SQL Server query to update the table
I used curser to update my table, and I get an error regards the conversion between date and varchar
The error is
`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`
I need help. I think the reason is I use dynamic SQL statement, and I try to replace it but with no. luck

here is the full query

```
 Declare update_cursor
    CURSOR  LOCAL 
    FOR
    (select  DISTINCT  hospital, dataset , table_name,COLUMN_NAME, source from dbo.input_table  where hospital= Hospital_name);
FOR UPDATE of hospital, dataset , table_name,COLUMN_NAME, source
    
    
    
    OPEN update_cursor
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM update_cursor INTO
                        @HospitalName,
                         @DS,
                         @tbl_nm,
                         @clmn_nm,
                         @source_v
    
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                if @source_v = 'A'  
                  begin 
                  set @MaxTimestamp_inSource = N'(select max(SYNC_TIMESTAMP) from '+@tbl_nm+')'
                  --EXEC sp_Executesql @MaxTimestamp_inSource
                  end
                 Else
                 begin
                  set @MaxTimestamp_inSource = N'(select max(INSETR_ETL_TS) from '+@tbl_nm+')'
                  EXEC   sp_Executesql @MaxTimestamp_inSource
                  end
    
            
                    update dbo.input_table
                    set MaxSynchTimestamp  = @MaxTimestamp_inSource
                    where 
                    agency = @HospitalName AND
                    dataset = @DS AND
                    table_name = @tbl_nm AND
                    column_name = @clmn_nm
    
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM update_cursor INTO
                        @HospitalName,
                         @DS,
                         @tbl_nm,
                         @clmn_nm,
                         @source_v
                        
    END
    CLOSE update_cursor
    DEALLOCATE update_cursor
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Encourage others to help you. Don't cram your code together. Use statement terminators. Don't add "extra" terminators that serve no purpose. Don't put multiple statements on one line. Write in a consistent style. And lastly, use whitespace to make your code easier to read. And you really need to understand how to implement effective error handling. Just rethrow the error - don't add to your problems.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.